# How to prevent tremolo buzzing?

Tags: guitar, tremolo-system

My Aria Mac 57/7 has a licensed Floyd Rose Tremolo.

Recently when I pick a note on the high E string on frets 12, 13 and 14, I hear a brief buzzing sound that appears to be coming from the tremolo/bridge. I'm sure it's coming from the tremolo area and not a result of fret buzz because if I hold the tremolo still, the buzzing stops.

I recorded the noise to give you an idea: http://cl.ly/1D0j283V1e0U2j2x443B

I can hear it when the guitar is not played through an amp and I think it doesn't have much affect on the guitars sound when it is played through an amp.

Could it be a loose/weak spring in the back of the guitar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try wrapping an elastic band around the Trem springs to see if that helps. It could be a lever spring vibing against a Fine Tuning/String Lock screw.[image]

Comment: As for the rubber band: while it would probably work, I would rather find out the root cause and solve that. Thanks for the heads up on the lever spring. I'll check that out too.

Comment: The rubber band was meant to help to diagnose rather than be the solution.